# Rails Fragment Caching on Product + Money gem exchange_to Rate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I am trying to fragment cache my products in Rails, but noticed that it won't switch the currency once cached. I am setting the current currency via a session variable like `session[:currency] = "USD"`.

In this Example, it wouldn't be able to display `<%= Money.new(p.price, "EUR").exchange_to("GBP") %>`, once the user switches his currency using this method.

```
<% Product.all.each do |p| %>
  <% cache(p) do %>
    <%= link_to p.name, product_url(p) %>
    <%= Money.new(p.price, "EUR").exchange_to(session[:currency]) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

How can I let rails cache the different `Money` objects, too and still use `exchange_to` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the currency to your cache key. That allows Rails to cache one version for each currency:

```
<% Product.all.each do |p| %>
  <% cache [p, session[:currency]] do %>
    <%= link_to p.name, product_url(p) %>
    <%= Money.new(p.price, "EUR").exchange_to(session[:currency]) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

See [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CacheHelper.html#method-i-cache) for keys that are dependending on multiple sources.